# Apple on blocking tabs on tabbar from being clickable until a criteria has been met

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

How does apple feel about blocking tabs from being clickable until for example when the user has clicked on a uitableview row on another tab?

Sometimes you may not want the content of another tab being accessible until a certain criteria has been met.

Example:

**Playlist Search Played Settings**

In this case I don't want the user to click on Search tab before having chosen a playlist in the Playlist tab.

Is this enough for the app to not be approved on the appstore?

Comment: Apple may not reject it, but it might go against what most users would expect.  You might want to consider adding/removing the search tab bar item with animation depending on whether or not a row is selected on your playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something similar to the music app, show an empty tab with an explanation as to why this tab is empty. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could change the available view controllers in the UITabBarController. When the user selects a certain row (as you have suggested), call

```
– (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)controllers
                  animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

So as you have suggested, don't add the search view controller until after they have selected a playlist.